# Currency Converter JavaScript projects flag issue

Tags: javascript

I submitted all of my code below for a better understanding. The code is fine, my question is: How can I perfectly show multiple countries with their country name list? I mean: When I change the country name, then the flag image should be changed automatically, so users see the country name and image. I already put many links in my **loadFlag()** function in my js file, but this is not working. Please help me, how can i do it with my code? Thanks in advance and love from the top of my heart.

```js
const droplist = document.querySelectorAll(".drop-list select");
fromCurrency = document.querySelector(".form select");
toCurrency = document.querySelector(".to select");
getButton = document.querySelector("form button")

let  country_code = {
    "AED" : "AE",
    "AFN" : "AF",
    "XCD" : "AG",
    "ALL" : "AL",
    "AMD" : "AM",
    "ANG" : "AN",
    "AOA" : "AO",
    "AQD" : "AQ",
    "ARS" : "AR",
    "AUD" : "AU",
    "AZN" : "AZ",
    "BAM" : "BA",
    "BBD" : "BB",
    "BDT" : "BD",
    "XOF" : "BE",
    "BGN" : "BG",
    "BHD" : "BH",
    "BIF" : "BI",
    "BMD" : "BM",
    "BND" : "BN",
    "BOB" : "BO",
    "BRL" : "BR",
    "BSD" : "BS",
    "NOK" : "BV",
    "BWP" : "BW",
    "BYR" : "BY",
    "BZD" : "BZ",
    "CAD" : "CA",
    "CDF" : "CD",
    "XAF" : "CF",
    "CHF" : "CH",
    "CLP" : "CL",
    "CNY" : "CN",
    "COP" : "CO",
    "CRC" : "CR",
    "CUP" : "CU",
    "CVE" : "CV",
    "CYP" : "CY",
    "CZK" : "CZ",
    "DJF" : "DJ",
    "DKK" : "DK",
    "DOP" : "DO",
    "DZD" : "DZ",
    "ECS" : "EC",
    "EEK" : "EE",
    "EGP" : "EG",
    "ETB" : "ET",
    "EUR" : "FR",
    "FJD" : "FJ",
    "FKP" : "FK",
    "GBP" : "GB",
    "GEL" : "GE",
    "GGP" : "GG",
    "GHS" : "GH",
    "GIP" : "GI",
    "GMD" : "GM",
    "GNF" : "GN",
    "GTQ" : "GT",
    "GYD" : "GY",
    "HKD" : "HK",
    "HNL" : "HN",
    "HRK" : "HR",
    "HTG" : "HT",
    "HUF" : "HU",
    "IDR" : "ID",
    "ILS" : "IL",
    "INR" : "IN",
    "IQD" : "IQ",
    "IRR" : "IR",
    "ISK" : "IS",
    "JMD" : "JM",
    "JOD" : "JO",
    "JPY" : "JP",
    "KES" : "KE",
    "KGS" : "KG",
    "KHR" : "KH",
    "KMF" : "KM",
    "KPW" : "KP",
    "KRW" : "KR",
    "KWD" : "KW",
    "KYD" : "KY",
    "KZT" : "KZ",
    "LAK" : "LA",
    "LBP" : "LB",
    "LKR" : "LK",
    "LRD" : "LR",
    "LSL" : "LS",
    "LTL" : "LT",
    "LVL" : "LV",
    "LYD" : "LY",
    "MAD" : "MA",
    "MDL" : "MD",
    "MGA" : "MG",
    "MKD" : "MK",
    "MMK" : "MM",
    "MNT" : "MN",
    "MOP" : "MO",
    "MRO" : "MR",
    "MTL" : "MT",
    "MUR" : "MU",
    "MVR" : "MV",
    "MWK" : "MW",
    "MXN" : "MX",
    "MYR" : "MY",
    "MZN" : "MZ",
    "NAD" : "NA",
    "XPF" : "NC",
    "NGN" : "NG",
    "NIO" : "NI",
    "NPR" : "NP",
    "NZD" : "NZ",
    "OMR" : "OM",
    "PAB" : "PA",
    "PEN" : "PE",
    "PGK" : "PG",
    "PHP" : "PH",
    "PKR" : "PK",
    "PLN" : "PL",
    "PYG" : "PY",
    "QAR" : "QA",
    "RON" : "RO",
    "RSD" : "RS",
    "RUB" : "RU",
    "RWF" : "RW",
    "SAR" : "SA",
    "SBD" : "SB",
    "SCR" : "SC",
    "SDG" : "SD",
    "SEK" : "SE",
    "SGD" : "SG",
    "SKK" : "SK",
    "SLL" : "SL",
    "SOS" : "SO",
    "SRD" : "SR",
    "STD" : "ST",
    "SVC" : "SV",
    "SYP" : "SY",
    "SZL" : "SZ",
    "THB" : "TH",
    "TJS" : "TJ",
    "TMT" : "TM",
    "TND" : "TN",
    "TOP" : "TO",
    "TRY" : "TR",
    "TTD" : "TT",
    "TWD" : "TW",
    "TZS" : "TZ",
    "UAH" : "UA",
    "UGX" : "UG",
    "USD" : "US",
    "UYU" : "UY",
    "UZS" : "UZ",
    "VEF" : "VE",
    "VND" : "VN",
    "VUV" : "VU",
    "YER" : "YE",
    "ZAR" : "ZA",
    "ZMK" : "ZM",
    "ZWD" : "ZW"
}


for( let i =0; i < droplist.length; i++) {
    
    for(let currency_code in country_code){
                let selected;
        if(i == 0){
            selected = currency_code == "USD" ? "selected" : "" ;
        }else if(i == 1){
            selected = currency_code == "BDT" ? "selected" : "";
        }
        let optionTag = `<option value="${currency_code}" ${selected}>${currency_code}</option>`;
        droplist[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", optionTag)
    }
    droplist[i].addEventListener("change", e=>{
        loadFlag(e.target)
    })
    
}

function loadFlag(e){
    for(code in country_code){
        if(code == e.value){
            let imgTag = e.parentElement.querySelector('img')
                    imgTag.src = ``

        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", () =>{
    getExchangeRate();
})


getButton.addEventListener("click", e =>{
    e.preventDefault() 
    getExchangeRate();
})

function getExchangeRate(){
    const amount = document.querySelector(".amount input")
    let exchangeRateTxt = document.querySelector(".exchange-rate")

    let amountVal = amount.value;
    if(amountVal == "" || amountVal == "0") {
        amount.value = "0";
        
    }
    exchangeRateTxt.innerText = 'Getting Exchange Rate....'
    let url = ` https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/d8bac7218d7178094bf9a6cb/latest/${fromCurrency.value}`;

    fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
        let exchangeRate = result.conversion_rates[toCurrency.value]
        let totalExchangeRate = (amountVal * exchangeRate).toFixed(2)
        exchangeRateTxt.innerText= `${amountVal} ${fromCurrency.value} = ${totalExchangeRate} ${toCurrency.value}`
    })
    
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,500;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300&display=swap');


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #675AFE
}

.wrapper{
    width: 370px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #fff;
}
.wrapper header{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper form{
    margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}

form :where(input, select, button){
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
form p{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
form input{
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

form input:focus{
    padding: 0 14px;
    border: 2px solid #675AFE;
}
form .drop-list{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.drop-list .select-box{
    display: flex;
    height: 45px;
    width: 115px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.select-box select{
    width: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 -5px 0 5px;
}
.select-box select::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 8px;
}
.select-box select::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: #fff;
}
.select-box select::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}
.select-box img{
    max-width: 25px;
}

.drop-list .icon{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

form .exchange-rate{
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px;
}

form button{
    height: 52px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #675AFE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
 <div class="wrapper">
     <header>Currency Converter</header>
     <form action="#">
         <div class="amount">
             <p>Enter Amount</p>
             <input type="text" value="1">
         </div>
         <div class="drop-list">

             <div class="form">
                 <p>Form</p>
                 <div class="select-box">
                    <img
                    src="https://flagcdn.com/48x36/br.png"
                    srcset="https://flagcdn.com/96x72/br.png 2x,
                      https://flagcdn.com/144x108/br.png 3x"
                    alt="Brazil">
                    <select>
                        
                    </select>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></div>

             <div class="to">
                <p>To</p>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <img
                    src="https://flagcdn.com/48x36/pk.png"
                    srcset="https://flagcdn.com/96x72/pk.png 2x,
                      https://flagcdn.com/144x108/pk.png 3x"
                    alt="Pakistan">

                   <select>
                      
                   </select>
                </div>
            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="exchange-rate">Getting Exchange Rate....</div>
         <button>Get Exchange Rate</button>
     </form>
 </div>


























    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading country flags from `flagcdn.com` in which each `png` is named after a two-letter country code that you have in your `country_code` value.

You just need to update your `loadFlag` function to properly update the `img` tag's property values. See the working code snippet below.

```js
const droplist = document.querySelectorAll(".drop-list select");
fromCurrency = document.querySelector(".form select");
toCurrency = document.querySelector(".to select");
getButton = document.querySelector("form button")

let country_code = {
  "AED": "AE",
  "AFN": "AF",
  "XCD": "AG",
  "ALL": "AL",
  "AMD": "AM",
  "ANG": "AN",
  "AOA": "AO",
  "AQD": "AQ",
  "ARS": "AR",
  "AUD": "AU",
  "AZN": "AZ",
  "BAM": "BA",
  "BBD": "BB",
  "BDT": "BD",
  "XOF": "BE",
  "BGN": "BG",
  "BHD": "BH",
  "BIF": "BI",
  "BMD": "BM",
  "BND": "BN",
  "BOB": "BO",
  "BRL": "BR",
  "BSD": "BS",
  "NOK": "BV",
  "BWP": "BW",
  "BYR": "BY",
  "BZD": "BZ",
  "CAD": "CA",
  "CDF": "CD",
  "XAF": "CF",
  "CHF": "CH",
  "CLP": "CL",
  "CNY": "CN",
  "COP": "CO",
  "CRC": "CR",
  "CUP": "CU",
  "CVE": "CV",
  "CYP": "CY",
  "CZK": "CZ",
  "DJF": "DJ",
  "DKK": "DK",
  "DOP": "DO",
  "DZD": "DZ",
  "ECS": "EC",
  "EEK": "EE",
  "EGP": "EG",
  "ETB": "ET",
  "EUR": "FR",
  "FJD": "FJ",
  "FKP": "FK",
  "GBP": "GB",
  "GEL": "GE",
  "GGP": "GG",
  "GHS": "GH",
  "GIP": "GI",
  "GMD": "GM",
  "GNF": "GN",
  "GTQ": "GT",
  "GYD": "GY",
  "HKD": "HK",
  "HNL": "HN",
  "HRK": "HR",
  "HTG": "HT",
  "HUF": "HU",
  "IDR": "ID",
  "ILS": "IL",
  "INR": "IN",
  "IQD": "IQ",
  "IRR": "IR",
  "ISK": "IS",
  "JMD": "JM",
  "JOD": "JO",
  "JPY": "JP",
  "KES": "KE",
  "KGS": "KG",
  "KHR": "KH",
  "KMF": "KM",
  "KPW": "KP",
  "KRW": "KR",
  "KWD": "KW",
  "KYD": "KY",
  "KZT": "KZ",
  "LAK": "LA",
  "LBP": "LB",
  "LKR": "LK",
  "LRD": "LR",
  "LSL": "LS",
  "LTL": "LT",
  "LVL": "LV",
  "LYD": "LY",
  "MAD": "MA",
  "MDL": "MD",
  "MGA": "MG",
  "MKD": "MK",
  "MMK": "MM",
  "MNT": "MN",
  "MOP": "MO",
  "MRO": "MR",
  "MTL": "MT",
  "MUR": "MU",
  "MVR": "MV",
  "MWK": "MW",
  "MXN": "MX",
  "MYR": "MY",
  "MZN": "MZ",
  "NAD": "NA",
  "XPF": "NC",
  "NGN": "NG",
  "NIO": "NI",
  "NPR": "NP",
  "NZD": "NZ",
  "OMR": "OM",
  "PAB": "PA",
  "PEN": "PE",
  "PGK": "PG",
  "PHP": "PH",
  "PKR": "PK",
  "PLN": "PL",
  "PYG": "PY",
  "QAR": "QA",
  "RON": "RO",
  "RSD": "RS",
  "RUB": "RU",
  "RWF": "RW",
  "SAR": "SA",
  "SBD": "SB",
  "SCR": "SC",
  "SDG": "SD",
  "SEK": "SE",
  "SGD": "SG",
  "SKK": "SK",
  "SLL": "SL",
  "SOS": "SO",
  "SRD": "SR",
  "STD": "ST",
  "SVC": "SV",
  "SYP": "SY",
  "SZL": "SZ",
  "THB": "TH",
  "TJS": "TJ",
  "TMT": "TM",
  "TND": "TN",
  "TOP": "TO",
  "TRY": "TR",
  "TTD": "TT",
  "TWD": "TW",
  "TZS": "TZ",
  "UAH": "UA",
  "UGX": "UG",
  "USD": "US",
  "UYU": "UY",
  "UZS": "UZ",
  "VEF": "VE",
  "VND": "VN",
  "VUV": "VU",
  "YER": "YE",
  "ZAR": "ZA",
  "ZMK": "ZM",
  "ZWD": "ZW"
}


for (let i = 0; i < droplist.length; i++) {

  for (let currency_code in country_code) {
    let selected;
    if (i == 0) {
      selected = currency_code == "USD" ? "selected" : "";
    } else if (i == 1) {
      selected = currency_code == "BDT" ? "selected" : "";
    }
    let optionTag = `<option value="${currency_code}" ${selected}>${currency_code}</option>`;
    droplist[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", optionTag)
  }
  droplist[i].addEventListener("change", e => {
    loadFlag(e.target)
  });

}

function loadFlag(e) {
  for (code in country_code) {
    if (code == e.value) {
      const country = country_code[code].toLowerCase();
      let imgTag = e.parentElement.querySelector('img')
      imgTag.src = `https://flagcdn.com/48x36/${country}.png`;
      imgTag.srcset = `https://flagcdn.com/96x72/${country}.png 2x, https://flagcdn.com/144x108/${country}.png 3x`;
      imgTag.alt = country;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  getExchangeRate();
})


getButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  getExchangeRate();
})

function getExchangeRate() {
  const amount = document.querySelector(".amount input")
  let exchangeRateTxt = document.querySelector(".exchange-rate")

  let amountVal = amount.value;
  if (amountVal == "" || amountVal == "0") {
    amount.value = "0";

  }
  exchangeRateTxt.innerText = 'Getting Exchange Rate....'
  let url = ` https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/d8bac7218d7178094bf9a6cb/latest/${fromCurrency.value}`;

  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
    let exchangeRate = result.conversion_rates[toCurrency.value]
    let totalExchangeRate = (amountVal * exchangeRate).toFixed(2)
    exchangeRateTxt.innerText = `${amountVal} ${fromCurrency.value} = ${totalExchangeRate} ${toCurrency.value}`
  })

};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,500;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #675AFE
}

.wrapper {
  width: 370px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper header {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper form {
  margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}

form :where(input,
select,
button) {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

form input {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

form input:focus {
  padding: 0 14px;
  border: 2px solid #675AFE;
}

form .drop-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.drop-list .select-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 45px;
  width: 115px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.select-box select {
  width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 -5px 0 5px;
}

.select-box select::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

.select-box select::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #fff;
}

.select-box select::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}

.select-box img {
  max-width: 25px;
}

.drop-list .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

form .exchange-rate {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
}

form button {
  height: 52px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #675AFE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Currency Converter</header>
    <form action="#">
      <div class="amount">
        <p>Enter Amount</p>
        <input type="text" value="1">
      </div>
      <div class="drop-list">

        <div class="form">
          <p>Form</p>
          <div class="select-box">
            <img src="https://flagcdn.com/48x36/br.png" srcset="https://flagcdn.com/96x72/br.png 2x,
                          https://flagcdn.com/144x108/br.png 3x" alt="Brazil">
            <select>

            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></div>

        <div class="to">
          <p>To</p>
          <div class="select-box">
            <img src="https://flagcdn.com/48x36/pk.png" srcset="https://flagcdn.com/96x72/pk.png 2x,
                          https://flagcdn.com/144x108/pk.png 3x" alt="Pakistan">

            <select>

            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="exchange-rate">Getting Exchange Rate....</div>
      <button>Get Exchange Rate</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Should you want to also update `alt` text of each flag image, you'll need to further update the data structure in `country_code` so that each country name and its flag and currency abbreviation will be avaiable.

Comment: Now Working Perfectly. Thank you so much.